# How to obtain width and height of image after rotating it?

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

How can I get the width and height of the image after rotating it using `imagerotate()` in PHP?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// File and rotation
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$degrees = 180;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);

// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
?>
```

But what I want to do before doing the output, is that I want to get the width and height of the rotated image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can do something similar to this:

```
$data = getimagesize($filename);
$width = $data[0];
$height = $data[1];
```

Another option is this:

`list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);`

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. I already tried that before posting here :)

Comment: So if it doesn't work, what does it do instead? Does it error, does it crash the server, does it return incorrect values? The width and height of an image shouldn't change if rotated 180 degrees

Comment: Can't you use it before you rotate it getting the image's height and width?

Comment: It says "Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string"
Its clearly mentioned in php doc that it must pass the path to image, not the image object

Comment: @aslamdoctor - You know the value of `$filename` you use when you do `$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);`... what do you get if you use that same `$filename` value in `$data = getimagesize($filename);` as per BeatAlex's suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

imagerotate returns an image ressource. Hence you cannot use getimagesize which works with an image file.
Use

```
$width = imagesx($rotate);
$height = imagesy($rotate);
```

instead.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. `getimagesize()` is for dimensions of the original file before rotation. `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` is for dimensions or the processed file after rotation.